# Nhibernate Flush causing Updates where there should be none

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I am using the Repo pattern, and I have set up tests to replicate my a HTTP request coming in and then causing dispose on a unit of work once a test has completed.

It appears that after executing a HQL statement, and then calling displose (which in turn calls flush) that it is causing an update across various elements.

Very bizzare - has anyone come across this before?

Here is my HQL statement and it's execution:

```
_session.CreateQuery("select distinct t from TaskEntity as t").List<T>()
```

I've pulled this back to it's simplest form - and note the HQL statement is not directly in the CreateQuery.

Here is the stack trace I am getting:

I

```
BM.Data.Informix.IfxParameterCollection.b(Int32 A_0)
IBM.Data.Informix.IfxParameterCollection.GetParameter(Int32 index)
System.Data.Common.DbParameterCollection.System.Collections.IList.get_Item(Int32 index)
NHibernate.Type.Int32Type.Set(IDbCommand rs, Object value, Int32 index)
NHibernate.Type.NullableType.NullSafeSet(IDbCommand cmd, Object value, Int32 index)
NHibernate.Type.NullableType.NullSafeSet(IDbCommand st, Object value, Int32 index, ISessionImplementor session)
NHibernate.Persister.Entity.AbstractEntityPersister.Dehydrate(Object id, Object[] fields, Object rowId, Boolean[] includeProperty, Boolean[][] includeColumns, Int32 table, IDbCommand statement, ISessionImplementor session, Int32 index)
NHibernate.Persister.Entity.AbstractEntityPersister.Update(Object id, Object[] fields, Object[] oldFields, Object rowId, Boolean[] includeProperty, Int32 j, Object oldVersion, Object obj, SqlCommandInfo sql, ISessionImplementor session)
NHibernate.Persister.Entity.AbstractEntityPersister.UpdateOrInsert(Object id, Object[] fields, Object[] oldFields, Object rowId, Boolean[] includeProperty, Int32 j, Object oldVersion, Object obj, SqlCommandInfo sql, ISessionImplementor session)
NHibernate.Persister.Entity.AbstractEntityPersister.Update(Object id, Object[] fields, Int32[] dirtyFields, Boolean hasDirtyCollection, Object[] oldFields, Object oldVersion, Object obj, Object rowId, ISessionImplementor session)
NHibernate.Action.EntityUpdateAction.Execute()
NHibernate.Engine.ActionQueue.Execute(IExecutable executable)
NHibernate.Engine.ActionQueue.ExecuteActions(IList list)
NHibernate.Engine.ActionQueue.ExecuteActions()
NHibernate.Event.Default.AbstractFlushingEventListener.PerformExecutions(IEventSource session)
NHibernate.Event.Default.DefaultFlushEventListener.OnFlush(FlushEvent event)
NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl.Flush()
Case.Data.SQL.NHibernateUnitOfWork.Dispose() in C:\Projects\Case System\Dev\WorkingBranch\Src\Case.Data.SQL\NHibernateUnitOfWork.cs: line 46
Case.Domain.Tests.TaskServicesTests.TakeDown() in C:\Projects\Case System\Dev\WorkingBranch\Src\Case.Domain.Tests\TaskServicesTests.cs: line 40
```

Comment: Can I ask how you have observed that lazy loading occurs?

Comment: I was watching it via NHibernate profiler - the issue seems to have disappeared, and is now being replaced by update statements trying to be called - I simply have a HQL statement being executed - I'll edit my question to suit..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I faced a similar problem. I'll first tell you what causes this. When `NHibernate` fetches an entity from the `DB` it assigns values to it's props. There are few props that have null values in the `DB` but are not of `Nullable` type in the class definition. So `NHibernate` assigns them a default value eg. `0` for `int`, `DateTime.MinValue` for `datetime` etc. When you call commit on the transaction, `NHibernate` rechecks the values of properties with `DB` values and since props which should have had `Null` values now have a default value, `NHibernate` thinks that the values have been changed and causes an update.

**Solution:**

1. Use `nullable datatypes` for your class props by post fixing them with
   `?` but for me this is causing other problems.
2. Map your properties as `Not Null` Types but this is not preferable in
   most cases.
3. The solution that I am using: I am assigning default values to the
   props in the entity's constructor, so instead of saving `Null` values
   in the `Db` `Nhibernate` saves some default value and this stops the
   calls to unnecessary updates.

You may further google `NHibernate ghostbuster` for more research on this problem.

Comment: Perfect! Despite being just over a year on... but that describes the problem perfectly! Everything now uses Nullable() and we also turned off TrackChanges functionality in NH

Answer (score 1):

NHibernate typically runs updates when it has transient or detached entities that it isn't sure about. That is, entities that it doesn't know if it has a parent for that manages it or if its not sure the entity is dirty. This is typically a symptom of a bad mapping somewhere (a missing Inverse on some parent) or you have no Version or Date column on your entities.